# FadingActionBar LinearLayout does not match parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I cannot get my LinearLayout to "match_parent" properly. As you can see on the screenshot, the white space at the bottom should not be. If I try to apply this background color directly to the style i get a weird result where every view on the Card itself is filled with the background color.
It worked before I implemented FadingActionBar:

[image: device-2014-03-11-184544]

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/AppBaseThemeCardBG"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_standard_padding"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventCard"
        style="@style/nowCardStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/eventDate"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeNormal" />

        <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/eventHead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeVeryLarge" />

        <com.mikebdev.douala.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/eventBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:typeface="roboto_condensed_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's definitely an issue in the library, I never tested it with content that didn't fill the entire viewport.

I've just pushed to Maven Central a new version (3.1.2) of the library that should solve the issue, please let me know how it works for you.